# ZAPI API : Need a API call to execute filter on a test cycle so that all the test cases present in filter will be added in test cycle

Tags: automation

I am working on a zapi/zypher integration and I need to create a test cycle at run time and add test cases into it.

The creation of test cycle have been done but I couldn't find any api call through which I can add test cases into it.

Rather than adding one by one test cases into cycle , I have created a filter over JIRA and want to execute this filter on that particular test cycle so that all the test cases present in filter , will add in test cycle.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this POST : http://localhost:2990/jira/rest/zapi/latest/execution
Update the Body :
{
  "13377": {
    "id": 13377,
    "orderId": 13377,
    "executionStatus": "-1",
    "comment": "",
    "htmlComment": "",
    "cycleId": -1,
    "cycleName": "Ad hoc",
    "versionId": 10001,
    "versionName": "Version2",
    "projectId": 10000,
    "createdBy": "vm_admin",
    "modifiedBy": "vm_admin",
    "assignedTo": "user1",
    "assignedToDisplay": "user1",
    "assignedToUserName": "user1",
    "assigneeType": "assignee",
    "issueId": 10013,
    "issueKey": "SAM-14",
    "summary": "Test",
    "label": "",
    "component": "",
    "projectKey": "SAM"
  }
}
```